# JQuery Mobile Popup not working in Android 4 emulator

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-emulator, popup

I create a popup as:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="confirmation-dialog"  data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="a" data-position-to="window">
     .......
</div>
```

it will be called from:

```
<a href="#confirmation-dialog" data-icon="logout" id="logout-button" data-rel="popup">Exit</a>
```

It is working in the browser but not working in the Emulator with Android 4.0.3

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Has the Emulator been updated to support the alpha version of JQM?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has the Emulator been updated to support jQuery Mobile 1.2 alpha?